# Couchbase lite API Reference

Tags: cordova, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I wonder where is reference API that would show how to use **Couchbase Lite** queries, crud functionality..

Going here (to official website doc page): http://www.couchbase.com/documentation

Doesn't help much. There just concepts, philosophy.

I'm interested in JS / PhoneGap side. But if go there: http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/cbl-phonegap/

There are again: concepts, philosophy, some pictures. Nice.. there are even some samples I can get from git-hub. But where is reference API?

---

There are some: http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-api-reference-1.1/couchbase-protocol_get.html (Thanks Google) I'm not sure if is Lite though..

But where for JS ? Or I better ask: What do you (who use Couchbase lite with for JS/Mobile) use as documentation?

Answer (score 1):

The current Couchbase Lite API can be found here in the autodocs:

http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-lite-ios-1.0b1/annotated.html

When a new version of the API is released (which is imminent I believe), I will update this answer with a new link.

Also, even if you are using JS, it's still interacting with a native Couchbase Lite, so you are still using API just as a native iOS app is using the API.

Here are some other links that can help, the README's might be useful as well as the source code for the TodoLite:
https://github.com/couchbaselabs/Couchbase-Lite-PhoneGap-Plugin
https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TodoLite-PhoneGap

Comment: it is not what I expect to see. I expected something like this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/crud/

Comment: we are in early beta for Couchbase Lite/Mobile and you are comparing it to something that has been around for years... :/ that's sort of a strange comparison.

Comment: Must be. I found this link/resource useful so far (at least for starting up): docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/cbl-phonegap 

But that sample comes with very strange set of js-frameworks. I would prefer AngularJS. It works ok on Android Emulator but it does not open at all in the browser. I understand that it should not work  in full in browser (because of some Android API is used there) but since it is demo, it could show at least something.

Comment: I highly recommend talking to our mobile team in our google group and you can get help, ask questions, etc. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mobile-couchbase

Comment: I have not seen strange "documentation" like the one available for Couchbase!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to use the REST API to access couchbase database from a phonegap/JS app.

> Additionally, apps built with web technologies, such as JavaScript,
>   can use the Couchbase Lite REST APIs to develop hybrid mobile apps.

Ref: http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/index.html

And, the REST API for Couchbase Lite can be found at : http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/references/couchbase-lite/rest-api/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the following document is good. It contains basic CRUD operations and some example codes.
[Couchbase Node.js SDK 2.0](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/node-2.0/documents.html)

I know, it is not pretty good such as MongoDB documentation. Unfortunately..